# Youtube / Google Style Carousel Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, google-plus, carousel

I would like to make a carousel slider similar to what you see on the new design for Youtube.com and pages like this: https://plus.google.com/discover/w29saB

Any recommendations on how to build this, or Jquery plugins that facilitate this.

I've tried itemSlide() but I don't know how to get the CSS so that it renders inside the container DIV properly.  Also Itemslide doesn't give the arrows to scroll to the next page.

Other carousel plugins I've looked at even with their responsive options, make you specify the number of items to fit on a page. I would like that to be determined by css.

**Update** I've gotten itemSlide() to render in the container div however I still need to be able to add the arrows so that it scrolls when clicked.  I figure getting the buttons to overlay is a matter of the right CSS.  Getting the scroll to work when clicked is likely something specific to the itemSlide api that I should be able to figure out once the arrows are overlaid properly.  itemSlide() as carousel slider library:  http://itemslide.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a DIV inside a DIV. Have the overlap as hidden in css. Arrows can be div buttons that move the inner div "X" number of pixels in a given direction to match the block sizes in the carousel stile div.

Comment: I'll try that.  One thing with overlap hidden is that in the Youtube example you can scroll the div without pressing the arrows.  How do I make sure the user is able to do that with overflow: hidden?  I could use overflow: auto, but I don't scrollbars to be visible.

Comment: If you set overflow as hidden, there will be no scroll bar unless you set overflow as scroll. Your example used arrows. If you want auto scrolling with mouse over, you will need to use jQuery. Plenty of examples around to get started with. But is more coding. As long as you don't mind.

Comment: So I got itemslide() working, and it indeed uses a div within a div.  Still need the right css to overlay the scroll arrows.  Also the Google examples are apparently intelligent enough to know when you've reached the start or end of the list and hide the arrows accordingly.  How to I detect if the user has scrolled to the end of the list with Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: Each thumbnail is a set size I expect. You have the start point already, so in your loop, you can workout the end. Then save in a var. if x = y, hide arrow. Not only solution, but it is just lateral thinking. try out ideas, it is fun to learn (^-^). Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the arrows overlaid you can use the disable_clicktoslide option of the library so that clicking on slides doesn't move to them.

To make the arrows work, call the functions next() and previous() on the carousel object.

Also you can use the function getActiveIndex() to detect where the user is on the carousel.

Good luck!